# Calling a class method for a route

Tags: php, class, slim

I've used Slim for several projects and I always was connecting routes to class methods, by doing `$app->route('/', array('MyClass', 'method'));`

However, after installing it with composer, this is the error I'm getting:

```
call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, non-static method Pages::home() should not be called statically
```

Here's the code:

```
class Pages {
  function home() {
    print 'home';
  }
}

$app = new \Slim\Slim();
$app->get('/', array('Pages', 'home'));
$app->run();
```

Did I miss something? Should I edit my class additionally?

Thanks!

Comment: the method you have provided is `page()`, not `home()`

Comment: Thanks for spotting that, it's updated.

Comment: http://docs.slimframework.com/ take a look here :) it expects second param to be a valid callback, try an anonymous function that contains the instance of the class and the method call?

Comment: Maybe the Slim version you were using was outdated? So using Composer you have installed a newer version in which that feature is not supported? In the docs there is no mention for this method of assigning routes.

Comment: Exactly my thoughts. It's only mentioned you can use functions in the current scope, but no `'class', 'method'` definition. I guess the old version of Slim was trying to map `$param[0]::$param[1]()` from the `get()` method thus making static call to `MyClass::method()`, which will be no longer supported for non-static method, which I guess make Slim to change their API for the next version using callbacks

Comment: Thank you both for your replies; yes, it's very possible that this is a version issue. I'll dig more into this and compare the Slim I used before and the new one.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Looks like your error reporting is turned up higher than it has been in the past, as I believe the error you're getting is an `E_STRICT` error.  If you changed your `function home()` method to `public static function home()` you'd no longer get the error.

That said, a better solution might be to try the new(-ish) [controller feature in Slim 2.4.0](https://github.com/codeguy/Slim/releases/tag/2.4.0).  Your new route would look like this:

```
$app->get('/', '\Pages:home');
```

Comment: Thanks Jeremy, that did the trick. I didn't notice your post on time, so I asked the same question on [Slim discussion forum](http://help.slimframework.com/discussions/questions/1284-has-class-method-as-route-callback-been-removed) and received the same answer.

Comment: @JeremyKendall how would it work with url parameters? $app->get('/book/:id', '\Book:getOne($id)')  this did not work....

Comment: got it -- $app->get('/book/:id', '\Book:getOne') -- only the method name is used in $app->get(). Then in the Book class, function getOne($id) { //code }

Answer (score 0):

The code is wrong, you are passing an array as a parameter instead of the callback. Try passing a function.

Documentation for GET Routes:
http://docs.slimframework.com/#GET-Routes

```
class Pages {
  function home() {
    print 'home';
  }
}

$app = new \Slim\Slim();
$app->get('/',function() {
    $page = new Pages();
    $page->home(); 
});
$app->run();
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but exactly the same code worked for me before; that way I can keep the routes as lean as possible and keep all code in classes.